# excel vlookup left,index, mirror same table without spaces

Tags: excel

[image: example table]

Hello everyone, i need an example from where to start .. i need a **mirror table without spaces**, tried with vlookup.. index&match but i don t have any value in right table to guide him, in the photo is the result for what i need, if i have an option in column C,D,E,F > mirror same row in left table with all data.In B column i will have about 50 products, and in right table column K only 20 without spaces between(of course, i will have <20 values in left table C-F). Thank you, i will offer more details if it s needed.

Comment: Add a helper column using (eg) counta() to indicate the number of items entered then filter your table to hide the zero rows for that column.

Answer (score 0):

To do it without a helper column... just put this formula in your "nr" column of the "To Buy list" and drag down:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,INDEX((A:A>MAX($J$1:$J3))*--(((1=C:C)+(1=D:D)+(1=E:E)+(1=F:F))>0),0,1),0)),"")
```

[image]

You can then use this ID with a simple INDEX/MATCH to pull through the other details.

EDIT: Adding a solution using a helper column at OP's request.

Add the helper column and enter this formula in the first cell, then drag down:

```
=IF(SUM($C4:$F4)>0,MAX($G$3:$G3)+1,"")
```

[image]

Then in your "To buy list" add an ID column with numbers 1 to the max possible.
You can then use INDEX/MATCH along with this ID to get the rest of the info.
In J4, enter this formula:

```
=IFNA(IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($I4,$G:$G,0))=0,"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH($I4,$G:$G,0))),"")
```

You can then drag this formula across to column "O", and then down as far as you need:

[image]

Comment: tried, i get name? error .. can you give me more easy than this ?:)

Comment: I don't think so. Not without a helper column  anyway. The formula isn't that complex when you break it down. It is basically an INDEX/MATCH. The second INDEX just allows you to specify multiple criteria. Please see my comment on your answer as to why it's not working for you.

Comment: =IFNA(IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($I4,$G:$G,0))=0,"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH($I4,$G:$G,0))),"") after i put exactly like in your photo, with this formula i get name? error

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If it is old, perhaps it doesn't have the IFNA function available? Try just `=IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($I4,$G:$G,0))=0,"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH($I4,$G:$G,0)))` and see if that works (apart from a few NAs instead of blanks)

Comment: i used vlookup with your helper column, i edit my previous post and uploaded some photos, my new question is, if i have text in rows, how i can make same ID (helper column)

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand what you are asking. But I strongly advise against using VLOOKUP.... ever. INDEX/MATCH does exactly the same thing, is faster, more flexible, and less fragile.

Comment: Sorry, i will try with index/match but is still hard for me to work with.. I don t understand very well, ok in my previous post i ve ask for an helper column with numbers and text în column C-F, the helper column you gave me it works only with numbers. Ex if i type anything "word/letter" my id column it doesn t take number 1,2,3,4..Hope you understand what i mean, and the biggest problem for now is the vlookup if i have an formula in column i need to take the result, it give error, isn t take the result, If you don t understand i can upload photo 's. Thank you for your activity in this thread

Answer (score 0):

@Gravitate

And from here?
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wA4p.jpg)

i don t have an helper column... i need to mirror this table, and if i try with sort> this table will be in same sheet and it will display very ugly :D

Comment: In your image, the formula is trying to find the max of $J$1:$J4. It should be $J$1:$J3. Otherwise it is trying to find the max of its self.

Comment: if i put j3, i get name? error, i can put a helper column.. but in the mirror table what criteria i need to put?thank you! you can share a vision with how it will be wih an helper column?again i need to say..thank you!

Comment: I don't know how it can. What formula do you have in cell J4 after changing $J$1:$J4 to $J$1:$J3? It should work if you have this formula in your cell J4: `=IFNA(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,INDEX((A:A>MAX($J$1:$J3))*--(((1=C:C)+(1=D:D)+(1=E:E)+(1=F:F))>0),0,1),0)),"")`